# How to load a file from git in terraform cloud?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-cloud

Is there a way to load lambda aka javascript file from github to terraform cloud?
I have tried many things like:
local-exec to execute curl to pull file.
HTTP data -> but this one unable to use it like js file:

```
data "http" "test-file" {
  url = "https://raw.github.com/test/test.js"
}
```

Nothing seems to work on Terraform cloud. Even though the first option for local-exec doing curl works on local but not on cloud. Has anyone done this before?